# Where is the flaw in my logic for left-rotating an array N times?

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I've been starting at this for an hour and can't figure out where I'm going wrong. My implementation is

```
static void LeftRotation(int[] arr, int d)
{
    int[] copy = arr.Select(val => val).ToArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        int j = i - d;
        arr[i] = j < 0 ? copy[copy.Length + j] : copy[j];           
    }
}
```

and `d` is the number of rotations.

e.g. `arr=[1,2,3,4]`, `d= 2` --> `arr=[3,4,1,2]`

Comment: What is the current output?

Comment: @4castle For `1 2 3 4 5`, `4` I am getting `2 3 4 5 1`

Comment: Why not just arr.push the output of arr.shift, N number of times?

Comment: @joshstrike okay. how would he do that in c#?

Comment: @IlianPinzon hah. I'm not a C# coder and didn't realize there is no array function to do that. How bizarre. Okay, it appears to me that copy.Length + j would be wrong. Should be copy.Length. Right?

Comment: Does the element that you want to be in `i` at the end come from `i + d` or `i - d`? Does this answer match what you do in your code?

Comment: Can't you just slice the array and join the front to the back ?

Comment: You could just write your code as `Array.Copy(arr.Skip(d).Concat(arr.Take(d)).ToArray(), arr, arr.Length);`.

Answer (score 2):

A different way, as an example:

```
static void LeftRotation(int[] arr, int d)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= d; i++)
    {
        //saves the first element
        int temp = arr[0];

        //moves each element to the left, starting from the 2nd
        for (int j = 1; j < arr.Length; ++j)
        {
            arr[j - 1] = arr[j];
        }

        //replaces the last elmt with the previously saved first elmt
        arr[arr.Length - 1] = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a quite nice alternative, though it might not best performant.

Comment: Correct, @Ghasan, it's not the most performant implementation. I just wanted to help others understanding by showing a very straight forward code.

Answer (score 0):

For one rotation, Swap lower index with the next higher one, until you reach the 2nd last element.

```
while (d-- > 0) {
    for(int i=0; i < arr.Length-1; i++) {
        swap(i, i+1);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DPkhNw

Comment: This is incorrect and unclear. Given an array of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and left shifting them by `1`, you would get `[2, 3, 4, 1, 5]`, where it should be `[2, 3, 4, 5, 1]`.

Comment: Yes, I wrote it via my phone...now it stands corrected.

Comment: Nice answer :) It is counter intuitive at first look (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Your are shifting left, but you shift the old value that used to exist in the array, instead of shifting the current looped element.

To make things simple, determine first your next position, and then use the index to go to that position in the original array (not `i` position), but get the value form the copy array.

```
static void LeftRotation(int[] arr, int d)
{
    int[] copy = arr.Select(val => val).ToArray();
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.Length; ++i)
    {
        int j = i - d;
        int position = j < 0 ? copy.Length + j : j;
        arr[position] = copy[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: It is nice to add a comment as you down vote, if you know what courtesy is, that is.

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is shifting *right* by `d` slots, not left.  To shift *left* you want the item from index `i+d` copied to index `i`, so change

```
int j = i - d;
```

to

```
int j = i + d;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. He is shifting left, except that he shifts the old value that used to exist in the array, instead of shifting the current looped element.

Comment: No, it is shifting right.  Try it with an input of 2 and you'll see that the elements are shifted right by 2.  Your method just copies the elements in a different sequence. (`copy[i] --> arr[i-d]` instead of `arr[i+d]=copy[i]`)